# Am I changing jobs too quickly?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-change

Here is my job history (Software Development):

A: 5 months

B: ~3 years

C: 11 months

D: 1 year 4 months (current)

I also have gaps on my resume (2 X 6month breaks) between AB and CD.

I'm currently looking out. Am I changing jobs too quickly (from market's perspective)?

Comment: why did the switches take place? Fired? moved cities? company went out of business?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say, as long as you can defend the reasoning behind short lived employments you'd be fine.

I wouldn't worry too much about the 1+ years as they could be seen as 'projects'. You'd need a good reason for the first one though, together with the gaps.

As for the gaps, I like this indeed article:

> There are a few easy-to-follow guidelines for how to address gaps in
>   your employment history:
>
> 1. Be prepared to talk about it
>
> Having a gap on your resume won’t necessarily prevent you from moving
>   successfully through the interview process. But potential employers
>   will expect an explanation. Take the time beforehand to work out how
>   you can address the gap in a way that projects confidence and
>   positivity.
>
> 2. Be honest
>
> You want to be truthful without going into unnecessary detail. A basic
>   template for your answer could be: “I [reason you were not employed].
>   During that time, [what you did during the gap]. Returning to work was
>   top of mind during that period and I’m ready to do that now.”
>
> Here are some examples of how you might fill in that template based on
>   your situation:
>
> If you left the workforce to be a caretaker: “I spent some time as the
>   primary caretaker in my family. During that time, I was able to be
>   there for my family but always knew I wanted to return to work. I’m
>   ready to do that now.”
>
> If you were laid off: “My former employer underwent a restructuring
>   that resulted in my position being eliminated. To be honest, it was a
>   difficult time. But I left with the confidence that I had developed
>   important skills there and built strong relationships with my managers
>   and colleagues. I’m looking forward to the opportunity to apply those
>   experiences in my next job.”
>
> If you were fired: “The company and I had different expectations. In
>   reflecting on that experience, I realize there are some things I could
>   have done differently. I learned a great deal and I’m excited about
>   the opportunity to bring that maturity to my next job.”
>
> If you took time off for personal reasons: “I was able to take some
>   time off work to focus on myself. It was a time that prepared me to
>   take on new challenges. I’m incredibly excited about the opportunities
>   that lie ahead, such as this position.”
>
> 3. Fill the gap
>
> While you don’t need to go into detail about what caused your
>   employment gap, you should give specifics on how you spent that time.
>
> Mention anything you read to keep up on the industry, how you stayed
>   in touch with colleagues, or what you’ve done to prepare for your
>   re-entry. Also bring up any freelance work, volunteer or community
>   positions you’ve held, classes or events you’ve attended, or any other
>   way you’ve advanced your professional skills. The goal is to convey
>   that you’ve been engaged even if you haven’t been formally employed.
>
> 4. Keep it brief and exit if you need to
>
> Many people take time off for one reason or another. Sometimes, these
>   reasons are personal and something you prefer to keep private.
>
> Once you’ve addressed the gap and explained what you did during that
>   time, steer the conversation back to your desire and ability to do the
>   job you’re interviewing for. You can do this by asking a question of
>   your interviewer once you’ve answered their question.
>
> If the conversation continues in a direction you are not comfortable
>   with, you have the option of saying: “I’d prefer not to go into more
>   detail. I am very interested in sharing details of my work experience,
>   however.” From there, you can supply another anecdote from your work
>   history that makes you qualified for the position.
>
> You may consider ending the interview at any time by saying, “I’m not
>   comfortable with where our conversation is headed so this may not be
>   the right fit. Thank you for your time.”

EDIT: personally I've seen a lot worse job history, in your case I'd get my story  straight and it should not be a problem at all.